# changing the title for the "Calenders in view"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, app

I have added a calender App to my SharePoint 2013, and then i have overlay calenders. the result is that i will have a view named "Calenders in view" , but since the name is misleading , so from where i can modify the link title ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That works for me

```
$(".ms-acal-apanel-title span").text('Title you want');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery as suggested in this article:

http://davecoleman146.com/2013/07/08/using-jquery-to-change-new-item-and-edit-titles-sharepoint-2013/

To change titles of links in SharePoint.

Instead of searching for 'new item' in the top filter, look for 'Calendars in View' and change it to what you think is more appropriate.  You dont need the second section of code searching for 'edit'.

Comment: thanks for the reply, it have changed the title, but i lost the .png calender image beside the link and also i lost the link format ... can you advice how i can chnage the title while keeping the original format and imag ?.

Comment: I cant exactly without seeing the code so post it here or send it to me in a message.  My guess is that you are using a text string that is longer than the original "Calendars in View" and this is blowing out the html column and hiding the png.  So try and short string to test that theory.  Please mark this as the answer if it has helped you.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){

$("a").filter (function() {
    return $(this).text() == 'Calendars in View';
    })
    .text("new title");
 
 
});